# Referencing vectors outside a data.table to perform operations

Tags: r, reference, data.table

**Note:** I am new to R and appreciate your help

The following is an elementary depiction of a much more complicated task I am seeking to perform. My data.table is named `preferences`, and here is 2 objects I have defined:

```
col <- "Pref_1"
name <- "Economic Commission for Latin America and the Caribbean \\(ECLAC\\)"
```

I want to perform the following operation (1) :

```
preferences[, "Pref_1"] <- gsub(x = preferences[, c("Pref_1")], pattern = "Economic Commission for Latin America and the Caribbean \\(ECLAC\\)", replacement = "A")
```

However, I want to do so using my objects `col` and `name` such that (2):

```
preferences[, col] <- gsub(x = preferences[, col], pattern = name, replacement = "A")
```

Since I defined `col` and `name` outside the data.table, it seems that data.table is unable to use them in this operation. How can I tell R to read expression (1) as expression (2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to do the following:

### Set up a simple example table

```
preferences <- data.table(
  Pref_1 = rep("Economic Commission for Latin America and the Caribbean (ECLAC)",3)
)
```

### This is what it looks like before trying to replace anything

```
                                                            Pref_1
1: Economic Commission for Latin America and the Caribbean (ECLAC)
2: Economic Commission for Latin America and the Caribbean (ECLAC)
3: Economic Commission for Latin America and the Caribbean (ECLAC)
```

### Now set up your col, pattern, and replacement

```
col = "Pref_1"
name = "Economic Commission for Latin America and the Caribbean \\(ECLAC\\)"
replacement = "A"
```

### Execute the replacement (notice that I wrap col in parentheses

```
preferences[,(col):=gsub(Pref_1, pattern = name,replacement = replacement)]
```

### This is what it looks like now

```
  Pref_1
1:      A
2:      A
3:      A
```